# Bind Dictionary with list in viewmodel to checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How do you properly bind a Dictionary and it's values per key to checkboxes?
I can display them in the HTTPGET but binding the selected values again to HTTPPOST doesn't seem to work.

viewmodel

```
public class EditViewModel
{
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Bar, List<BarVersionEditVM>> Matrix { get; set; }
}

public class BarVersionEditVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public bool IsSupported { get; set; }
}
```

view:

```
<form asp-action="Edit">
<div class="row">
 @foreach (var kvp in Model.Matrix.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key.Name))
 {
   <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
     <fieldset>
         <legend>@kvp.Key.Name</legend>
        @foreach (var version in kvp.Value)
        {
          <div>
           <input type="checkbox" id="@version.ID" value="@version.IsSupported" name="@version.Name" @(version.IsSupported ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "") />
               <label>@version.Version:</label>
         </div>
        }
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  }
  </div>
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Foo.ID" />
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
</form>
```

In the View I tried also to rewrite with foreach and using Html helpers, but without success:

@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Matrix[kvpair.Key][i].IsSupported)

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(EditViewModel vm) {
 // vm is there but Matrix  are null.
// and only the ID of Foo property is filled in.
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: The `DefaultModelBinder` will not bind to a Dictionary where the Value is a complex object or collection unless its in the format `propertyName[indexer].Key="", propertyName[indexer].Value=""` - in your case - `name=Matrix[0].Key=".."`, `name="name=Matrix[0].Value[0].ID=".."`, `name="name=Matrix[0].Value[0].Name =".."` etc, (and there are no helper methods that will generate the correct name attributes for you). It would be far easier to create a view model representing you view rather than using a `Dictionary`

Comment: For example `EditViewModel` contains `List<BarVM>` and `BarVM` contains `List<BarVersionEditVM>` and then use `nested `for` loops (or custom `EditorTemplates` for the types)

Comment: But if that's all you displaying/editing in the view, your view models can be far simpler.

Comment: ok let me give that a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless your `Dictionary` has simple value types for both the `Key` and `Value` (e.g. public `Dictionary<string, string>`), the `DefaultModelBinder` requires that the form control `name` attributes be in the format

```
<input .... name="Matrix[0].Key" value="..." />
<input .... name="Matrix[0].Value[0].ID" value="..." />
<input .... name="Matrix[0].Value[0].Name" value="..." />
```

There are no `HtmlHelper` methods that will generate the correct html to allow binding to your `Dictionary`.

It is far simpler to create simple view model(s) to with `IList<T>` properties for the collections. Based on the view you have shown, those models would be

```
public class EditVM
{
    public int FooID { get; set; }
    public List<BarVM> Bars { get; set; }
}
public class BarVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<BarVersionVM> Versions { get; set; }
}
public class BarVersionVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } // not clear where you use this property
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public bool IsSupported { get; set; }
}
```

and your view would then be

```
@model EditVM
....
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FooID)
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Bars.Count; i++)
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>@Model.Bars[i].Name</legend>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Bars[i].Name) // in case you need to return the view in the POST method
        @for(int j = 0; j < Model.Bars[i].Versions.Count; j++)
        {
            <div>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Bars[i].Versions[j].ID)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Bars[i].Versions[j].IsSupported)
                @Html.LabelFor((m => m.Bars[i].Versions[j].IsSupported, Model.Bars[i].Versions[j].Version)
            </div>
        }
    </fieldset>
}
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```