# MVC Binding "action", "controller" and "id" to collection parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller action which takes this parameter (among many)

```
Dictionary<String,HttpPostedFileBase[]> images
```

Under certain circumstances the input 'images' might not exist in the posted data.

When it does not exist, MVC somehow binds the following key/value collection to the images collection object:

```
{"controller","Products"},{"action","Edit"},{"id","xyz"}
```

(where xyz is the id being posted)

of course this causes the modelstate to be invalid because the strings "Products", "Edit" and "xyz" cannot be converted to HttpPostedFileBase

As long as the form does contain this collection (even if there are no actual files attached) it bind correctly).

Using VisualStudio 2015 and MVC 5.2.3.0

(the action is being routed to the correct controller/action)

Edit: I just noticed that this value is also being bound to a another Dictionary which also does not appear in the post under certain circumstances. (which doesn't generate errors, but it's obviously the wrong data).

Comment: How/where are you seeing this key/value collection?

Comment: @DavidG I'm seeing it as the value for this parameter when debugging.

Comment: What do you mean "for this parameter"? The debugger shows you these values when you hover over `images`?

Comment: @DavidG yes when I hover and also in the 'Locals' panel (actually it shows these keys with blank values, but when I dig into the modelstate errors I can see the strings "Products", "Edit" and "xyz" in the AttemptedValue property of the modelstate entries)

Comment: The `DefaultModelBinder` does not work well with Dictionaries (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41258733/bind-dictionary-with-list-in-viewmodel-to-checkboxes/41560929#41560929) for one of the issues), you can solve this by making the parameter `List<someModel>` where `someModel` contains properties `string` and `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thanks, I'll have to test that one of these days (for now I just made sure the items were always in the view).