# Binding to property on Dictionary object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a `Dictionary<int, PostCode>` called `PostcodeData` in an MVC4 VM. I'm trying to bind to the Serialized property on the `PostCode` DTO. In Razor, I've tried:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PostcodeData [code.Id].Serialized)
```

And

```
<input type="hidden" name="PostcodeData[@code.Id].Serialized"  />
```

But the dictionary is empty when the page posts back. According to [ASP.NET MVC Binding to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191303/asp-net-mvc-binding-to-a-dictionary) I should be able to bind to it though. Am I missing something?

Comment: What HTML did `<input type="hidden" name="PostcodeData[@code.Id].Serialized"  />` generate? _Use View Source in the browser._

Comment: @mjwills <input type="hidden" name="PostcodeData[1].Serialized">

Comment: That is not possible - refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41258733/bind-dictionary-with-list-in-viewmodel-to-checkboxes/41560929#41560929) for how you would need to bind to a `Dictionary`. But since you are not editing it, the why are you trying to send to back again unchanged?

Comment: I'm modifying it with JavaScript, the value stored represents a value in a series of checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke - I've experimented a range of fields from that post but nothing is working. Having a list isn't really feasible.

Comment: Did you read the link? (you would need to create an input for each property of `PostCode` plus the key)